# Как рекурсивно обойти html-дерево на python?

Tags: html, python, xml

Есть меню сайта в *html* - сделано через вложенные списки:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="cat">Cat</a></li>
    <li><a href="cat2">Cat2</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="subcat">Subcat</a></li>
            <li><a href="subcat2">Subcat2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="cat3">Cat3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Уровень вложенности везде разный (максимальный - 3, но желательно этого не предполагать)

Это меню нужно превратить в таблицу:

```
"Cat" url
"Cat2" url
"Cat2" "Subcat" url
```

и т.д.

То есть нужно взять и обойти рекурсивно дерево.

Какими библиотеками пользоваться (использую *python3*)? Как обойти дерево рекурсивно, не зная глубины?

Comment: Можно воспользоваться [xml.etree.ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) - это вполне нормальное решение, но надо помнить, что оно "not secure against maliciously constructed data" (т.е. надо понимать, откуда мы берём входной html).

Comment: покажите код. В чём сложности: ясно ли как можно распарсить  строку с html в какой-либо Python объект с древовидной структурой (или прямо на ходу можно печатать): что google говорит, если искать по словам: python3 html? 2. как обойти зависит от конкретного объекта (не обязательно, что интерфейс рекурсивный) 3. С рекурсией можно потренироваться на дереве директорий. Вот [пример кода для противоположной задачи (генерация html для заданной директории)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10961991/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать библиотеку [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).
Там у объекта супа есть свойство `.descendants`, пример смотри [тут](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants).
И уже в самом цикле ты делаешь соответствующие проверки, которые тебе нужны, а так же создаешь нужную структуру на выход.